# Callback not waiting for previous function to finish.

Tags: javascript

If **callbacks** are supposed to allow one function to wait for another function to finish before being called, why does the following not work?

```
function doHomework(subject, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`)
    }, 1000)
    callback()
}

function finishHomework() {
    console.log('Homework Finished!')
}

doHomework('chemistry', finishHomework)
```

This **outputs** the following:

```
Homework Finished!
Starting my chemistry homework.
```

But it should be **the other way around**. Why doesn't the callback wait for the setTimeout to finish before being called?

Comment: Try reading [Up and Running with Asynchronous JavaScript](https://medium.com/@rcepeda1993/async-js-the-complete-guide-670b4cf906c6)

Comment: That's because you are calling `callback` outside of the `setTimeout` callback. *"Why doesn't the callback wait for the setTimeout to finish before being called?"* Because that's not how `setTimeout` (or any async code) works. If you want A to happen after B is done, you have to execute A when B tells you that it is done. When `setTimeout` is done, it calls the callback passed to it.

Comment: Recommended watching: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to understand JS's execution model. Since JS was intended to run in a GUI, it is event driven thus runs in an event loop. This means that the main thread is executing your script, but other threads may work on ready-work enqueued by the main thread.

```
for (;;)
  if event = dequeueWork()
    handleEvent(event)
  else
    sleep(SOME_TIME)
```

When your script is interpreted, the JS engine knows that `doHomework()` has a timeout event registration. Timeouts are like sleeps in other languages, but because this is an event-loop model, we cannot block the GUI. So this function actually is handled by a background thread. When the duration has elapsed, then the main thread is notified  -- this is how all IO is  handled in JS.

Understanding this, it's easy to see what's happening: the callback is being fired right after the timeout event was *registered*.

[image]
*from c-sharpcorner.com*

To fix this, as others have mentioned, you'll need to call the callback inside timeout's callback:

```js
function doHomework(subject, callback) {
    console.log(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`)

    setTimeout(function() {
        callback();
    }, 1000);
}

function finishHomework() {
    console.log('Homework Finished!')
}

doHomework('chemistry', finishHomework)
```

Of course we're all not lucky enough to finish our homework 1sec after starting ;)

Helpful resources:

- [The Node.js Event Loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/)
- [v8](https://v8.dev/)
- [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey)

Comment: But if I place the callback inside setTimeout, then there is no proof that callbacks wait for something to be finished. In this case, my callback is acting like any other function, getting called in the order it's written, but not waiting for anything to finish.

Comment: Please reread my answer or the recommended article carefully. If you still have questions, I'll be happy to elaborate.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty It is (historically, not so much recently). Check out how the event loop works to understand how asynchronous things are possible in a single thread.

Comment: I know all about the event loop and asynchronous programming.  I think you referring to threads could be misleading.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael. I can see how the JS Engine recognizes setTimeout as a callback function, and therefore passes it off to the WebAPI and the callback queue, at which point the event loop can place onto the call stack for execution. That all makes sense. But then why isn't my custom callback also recognized as a callback, and this placed into the callback queue? Why is my custom callback treated differently than setTimeout? It sounds like we must use functions like setTimeout or Ajax for the JS Engine to recognize callbacks as such.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are wondering why your function isn't asynchronous while setTimeout is. This is a great question. Callbacks are  only used to *handle* async code, however, *not define* async code. setTimeout is async out-of-the-box (provided by the js std lib) just like XMLHttpRequest (as you noted). Please read the article I recommended carefully. As an aside, when you use an async function, directly or indirectly, the caller is also considered async.

Comment: I see. I was originally under the impression that callbacks allowed us to define custom async functions. But I see now that, as you explained, callbacks are not used to define async code, but rather to work with existing async primitives available from the few native JS functions that have access to the event loop (e.g. setTimeout). Thank you! It seems there should be a way to wait for a previous function to finish, rather than guessing how much time to add to setTimeout, but perhaps I need to learn about promises/observables. Thanks again!

Comment: @Cybernetic: Technically a "callback" is just a function passed to another function and is called by that other function. A function you pass to `Array#map` is a also a callback (i.e. `[1,2,3].map(x => x + 1)`). There is no implication whatsoever when/how it is executed. That is at the discretion of the function that receives the callback.

Comment: @Cybernetic Yes exactly :) One last thing (for clarification), you don't have to guess when a previous async function finishes since you can always perform side-effects in its callback (like calling `callback()` in `setTimeout`'s callback above). In this way, you can force an execution order without blocking the main thread. Unfortunately, calling callbacks within callbacks within callbacks, and so on, is known as *callback hell* and is ill-advised. Promises are the standard abstraction to mitigate this (by chaining `then`s).

Answer (score 0):

A `callback` is the name of something which is executed in the future, your callback is not being executed in the future, is being executed right after calling the function `setTimeout`.

What you actually want to do is call the function `finishHomework` one second in the future, therefore, you have to put that `callback` within the handler of the function `setTimeout` as follow:

```js
function doHomework(subject, callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(`Starting my ${subject} homework.`);
        // Here depends of your needs, in this case the callback
        // will be called after all the previous logic is executed.
        callback()
    }, 1000)

}

function finishHomework() {
    console.log('Homework Finished!')
}

doHomework('chemistry', finishHomework)
```